# How can I output the right micro symbol (not the greek character mu) in R?

Tags: r

The labels of my figures contain units like micromol m^-2 s^-1,so how can I output the right micro symbol?

I know that many people use the greek character mu, but mu is not the right symbol.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the greek symbol mu to stand in for micro? Of course that's the right symbol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix

Comment: So what is the right symbol in your case? Do you have any sort of reference?

Comment: @markhogue yes you are right, I don't want the greek symbol. I tried expression(micro) but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @MrFlick  The micro symbol is the right one. If you check the unicode of micro and mu (Greek), yu can see they are two different symbols, and they look slightly different.

Comment: Wee if you know the unicode character, then you can just insert that in the string: `plot(1,1,main=expression("\U00B5"^2 * s^{-1}))` (assuming that's the character you where describing, there are a lot of unicode characters)

Comment: @MrFlick It works!  Thank you very much!